# Creating a sharepoint list defaults are missing in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, visual-studio-2015

[image: Visual Studio]

Inside visual studio 2015, when I am trying to create a list the dropdown box is missing values. Not sure what to do from here. I have looked it up and its supposed to populate it. So like one of the values that is supposed to be on here is called "default blank" so I can create a new list with blank values.

Update Uninstalled visual studio 2015 and installed 2012 and still running into the same issue.